# masking data in logstash using web service

Tags: http, plugins, logstash

I am receiving data using Logstash (2.3) and want to mask them or add additional field, all using external web service as a source.

I have a web service available at something like: 
someserver:8080/webpage?id=1

I would like to extract a value that I get using this URL, and inject it into data.

my config file looks like:

```
input {
        file {
          path => "/opt/logstash/test/*.csv"
          start_position => "beginning"
         sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash/test/output/test.db"
}
        http { url => "http://localhost:8080/webpage"
      }
}

filter {
        csv {
                columns => ["col1", "col2", "col3" ]
                separator => ","
                skip_empty_columns => true
        }
}

output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
        csv {
                fields => ["col1","col2","col3" ]
                path => "/opt/logstash/test/output/test.csv"
        }
}
```

what I would like to achieve is to replace each col1 value with a value obtained from such external source.
I found http plugin, but it doesn't look straight forward to me.

tnx

Comment: translate filter replaces values, however not from a webservice. That sounds like a pretty bad idea generally (adding network latency to every event coming through your stack is not a good design choice). Apart from that there is no plugin (that i know of) that does this for you (http is an input plugin not a filter). You would have to write your own filter to support doing http requests to an external service and handling the response correctly. I would recommend rethinking your approach and using the translate filter instead.

Comment: I agree with pandaadb that your design may have a problem. You can use the ruby filter to do the request and the filtering instead of writing your own filter plugin (cf https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-example for an explanation to filter development).

Comment: That is a good point - the ruby plugin will do what you want :) Forgot about that guy. Re the translate filter: The translate filter is driven off a yaml. You can use a yaml and configure that with logstash. Then write a cronjob that queries your webservice to populate the yaml. Logstash will automatically refresh the yaml every so often (config) and you will have a super quick lookup without any added latency since your webservice is queries async at that point.

Comment: @pandaadb Good idea, I did not know it was possible. And I should I have put in my comment that using the ruby filter for this is not a good idea.

Comment: Tnx for your help. Initial response is correct, that this is not the best way, but I have no other options.

At the end, I made it by using http filter. I could post the config.